contextPath is not allowed to appear in element oxm:jaxb2-marshaller, when upgrading to Spring Framework 5
Background

Upgrading from Spring Framework 4.3.30.RELEASE to 5.0.20.RELEASE
Using oxm:jaxb2-marshaller

Problem
After upgrading the Spring Framework dependency version, the application fails to start because of:
Offending resource: class path resource [spring/application-context.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 77 in XML document from class path resource [spring/services/adapters.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 77; columnNumber: 90; cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'contextPath' is not allowed to appear in element 'oxm:jaxb2-marshaller'.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:72) ~[spring-beans-5.0.20.RELEASE.jar:5.0.20.RELEASE]
...
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 77 in XML document from class path resource [spring/services/adapters.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 77; columnNumber: 90; cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'contextPath' is not allowed to appear in element 'oxm:jaxb2-marshaller'.
...
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'contextPath' is not allowed to appear in element 'oxm:jaxb2-marshaller'.

Code
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:oxm="http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm-3.2.xsd">

...

<!-- Line 77 is: -->

<oxm:jaxb2-marshaller id="someMarshaller" contextPath="com.marshallable.jaxb" />


Looks like starting with Spring Framework 5, internally, Spring wants something that's compatible with spring-oxm-4.0.xsd where contextPath changed to context-path.
The fix was to update the schemaLocation to use spring-beans-4.0.xsd and spring-oxm-4.0.xsd and also change the contextPath property to context-path like so:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:oxm="http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm-4.0.xsd">

...

<oxm:jaxb2-marshaller id="someMarshaller" context-path="com.marshallable.jaxb" />


It is always recommended to use the versionless xsd files. Those will point to the one belonging to your specific version of Spring.
